# Google Script Errror: "Incorrect range width" when using setValues

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

Try as I might I CANNOT decipher the problem that I'm having writing new rows to a sheet.  I've done this several times and I've debugged this thoroughly using Logger.log, but I just can't solve it.  Here's a summary of what I'm doing, a code snippet, and a log:

What I'm doing:

- Adding rows to a sheet (below existing rows)
- 73 new rows are stored stored in array:  Grade Rows
- When attempt to write the new rows to the sheet, get this error:
  Incorrect range width, was 1 should be 26

Here’s the code including some Logger.logs:

---

```
var BeginningRow = LastSGRowSheet + 1;

var EndingRow = BeginningRow + SGPushKtr -1;

Logger.log("BeginningRow =>" + BeginningRow + "<=, SGPushKtr =>" + SGPushKtr + "<=, Ending Row =>" + EndingRow + "<=");

var GradesRangeString = 'A' + BeginningRow + ':' + LastStudentGradesColumnLetter + EndingRow;

Logger.log("GradesRangeString =>" + GradesRangeString + "<=");

StudentGradeSheet.getRange(GradesRangeString).setValues(GradeRows);
```

---

The error occurs in that last line of code.

Here’s the log:

> 17-12-31 11:51:15:763 EST] BeginningRow =>364<=, SGPushKtr =>73<=, Ending Row =>436<=
>   [17-12-31 11:51:15:764 EST] GradesRangeString =>A364:Z436<=

Comment: A little more information:  There are 26 columns in the sheet to which I'm writing.  That is where the "26" comes from in the error.

Comment: How is `GradeRows` defined?  I know you've mentioned it in your text above the code, but please edit your question to include the code that creates it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that your data array is dA then the number of rows in that array is dA.length and assuming its a rectangular array then the number of columns is vA[0].length.  So your output command has to be some thing like this.

```
sheet.getRange(firstRow,firstColumn,dA.length,dA[0].length).setValues(dA);
```

> If you'd like to learn a little more about this problem check [this](https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/javascript-array-difficulties) out.

You could also append each row to the current sheet one row at a time in loop.

Comment: Thanks for the input Cooper.  I began programming in google Script this past summer to develop a particular grading application (I'm a teacher).  I've needed to read & write data to & from sheets using arrays to stay  under the 5 minute time limit for Google Scripts.  I've written data to sheets using arrays in my project 5 or 6 times.  I've always used a string including values such as "A4:Z100" to describe the "to" range.  As opposed, that is, to your method of sending 4 parameters to describe the to range.  And it's always worked for me.  But it can't hurt to try your method.  I'll  do that

Comment: A way to work around the apps script execution limit is to use an external trigger from a Javascript timeout function in an html dialog.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know why GradeRows doesn't match your range without seeing all of your code.
Using Cooper's getRange arguments will likely reveal your problem, and will prevent you from having to update your row and column variables when you make changes to your code. Another issue that gets me sometimes is the fact that the setValues array needs to be exactly the same dimensions as the range. If one row has a different length, it will fail. If the logic I use to create row arrays can result in different lengths, I use the function below to make sure my arrays are symmetric before writing them to a sheet. It is also helpful for debugging.

```js
/** 
 * Takes a 2D array with element arrays with differing lengths
 * and adds empty string elements as necessary to return 
 * a 2D array with all element arrays of equal length.
 * @param {array} ar
 * @return {array}
 */
function symmetric2DArray(ar){
  var maxLength;
  var symetric = true;
  if (!Array.isArray(ar)) return [['not an array']];
  ar.forEach( function(row){
    if (!Array.isArray(row)) return [['not a 2D array']];
    if (maxLength && maxLength !== row.length) {
      symetric = false;
      maxLength = (maxLength > row.length) ? maxLength : row.length;
    } else { maxLength = row.length }
  });
  if (!symetric) {
    ar.map(function(row){
      while (row.length < maxLength){
        row.push('');
      }
      return row;
    });
  }
  return ar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using appendRow()? That way you don't need to do lots of calculations about the range. You can loop through your data and add it row by row. Something like this:

```
myDataArr = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
myDataArr.forEach(function(arrayItem){
  sheet.appendRow([arrayItem[0],arrayItem[1]])
})
// This will output to the sheet in three rows. 
// [1][2]
// [3][4]
// [5][6]
```